# Handling different status codes in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Here is my controller and factory:

```
angular.module('app').controller('userCtrl', function($scope, User) {
    $scope.users = [];

    User.getUsers().then(function(response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
    });
});

angular.module('app').factory('User', function($http) {
    return $http.get('api-url-here').then(function(response) {
        return response;
    }, function(error) {
        return error;
    });
});
```

If there is no users, backend returns status code **404**, or if there is internal server error, it returns status code **500**. Otherwise it returns status 
code **200** and users array.

In my AngularJS application, how I should show different messages depending on status code? I would like to have different messages on same status code in different pages.

Comment: Just use the `response.status` field https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Is this best practice? @OvidiuDolha

Answer (score 1):

```
// Defining your application module here in below.
var app = angular.module('app',['']);
// Using your application module defining your controller with dependency injection here in below.
app.controller('userCtrl',function($scope,User){
 //Defining your getUser function using ECMA-5 syntax here in below.
   $scope.getUser = function(){
 // Using your factory named User calling the factory function getUsers().
           User.getUsers().fetch({},function(respose){
                if(respose.status == 200){ // using this way you could find the status of the response here.
                   var _data = angular.fromJson(respose.data);
                   $scope.users = _data;
                }
           }, function(respose){
              $scope.users = [];
           });
    };
});
// Defining your factory service using your application module here in below.
app.factory('User',['$resource',$http, function($resource, $http){ 
var factory = {};
factoryName.getUsers = function(){
    return $resource('api-url-here', {}, {
    fetch: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true,
        header: {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Authorization' : Authorization
        },
        interceptor : {
            response : function(data) {
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
    })
};
return factory;
}]);
```